# SQLITE no such table: error IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Im have been using sqlite as a store in my app and everything was going fine problem is i changed my database schema deleted the old one and then inserted the new one in and now the application no longer loads any data despite all of the sql statements working fine whenever i run them in the firefox plugin. I have done a build clean and reset the simulator as well as delete the app in the simulator does anyone have any ideas whats going on?

Comment: I think you need to show your changed schema and a SQL query that doesn't work (at a minimum).

Comment: Have u solved the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

-Have you copied the new database to the documents directory in the appdelegate?

-After deleting the app from the simulator, and do a clean all, it should copy the database to the app's documents directory. Or if you won't change the database, you can delete the old and copy the new one every start.